# Using unpack to write a byte array with hex characters?

Tags: ruby

I want to take a value like:

```
ff0000
```

and make it into a byte array containing those hex values:

```
\xff\x00\x00
```

I'm not clear on how to do this using [`str.unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000760)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"ff0000".scan(/../).map { |match| match.hex } #=> [255, 0, 0]
```

or

```
("ff0000".scan(/../).map { |match| match.hex }).pack('C*') #=> "\377\000\000"
```

Depending on what format you want it in.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure unpack can do this. Try this instead:

```
"ff0000".gsub(/../) { |match| match.hex.chr }
```